# How to make my search for multiple columns procedure more efficient?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a stored procedure that searches across multiple columns in a combined table.

It works, however, it takes 15 seconds to search for a value in that combined table. The table takes 9 seconds to load so I'm not sure, maybe it's because my table too big?

So I'm just wondering if there's a way to make this query runs faster.

This is my stored procedure:

```
create procedure LRMWEB_Search

  @input nvarchar(1500)

AS

  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT tr.ResourceID , 
         tr.ProjectFile, 
         tr.ResourceFile, 
         tr.ResourceName, 
         trt.Culture, 
         trt.TranslatedFlag, 
         trt.TranslatedValue, 
         tr.Comments, 
         tr.IsApproved
  FROM       tblResourcesTranslated_NEW trt
  INNER JOIN tblResources_NEW           tr  ON trt.ResourceID = tr.ResourceID
  where tr.ResourceID       like '%'+ @input + '%'
     OR tr.ProjectFile      like '%'+ @input + '%'
     OR tr.ResourceFile     like '%'+ @input + '%'
     OR tr.ResourceName     like '%'+ @input + '%'
     OR tr.ResourceValue    like '%'+ @input + '%'
     OR tr.Comments         like '%'+ @input + '%'
     OR trt.Uid             like '%'+ @input + '%'
     OR trt.TranslatedValue like '%'+ @input + '%'
  ;
```

Comment: What's the bigger table? You could try and limit the results from that table FIRST before joining to the second table.

Comment: You might have better luck with `CHARINDEX()` instead of `LIKE`.  ex. `where CHARINDEX(@input,tblResources_NEW.ResourceID)>0...OR...`

Comment: You're using a leading wildcard and are forcing a full table scan. IMHO you need to either change your requirements (no leading wildcard + indizes + minimum length of input) or change the technique you're using (google/bing full text catalog) or live with slow performance.
Besides those three you may take an additional look into your design - it looks like earch column is a (n)varchar and guessing from the name Uid should be an uniqueidentifier (although it won't affect performance in your case)

Comment: This is cute but never will be a great performer. Also, it doesn't make sense to use `Like` on numeric data types. Imagine if your `@input` is `1` - it will return too many results.

Comment: @JiggsJedi: Nice thought, but that makes the table columns an *evaluated expression* rather than a column reference and so ineligible for index usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any use of `like` precludes an index, unless it has a fixed prefix with a wildcard suffix, such as `where foo like 'bar%'`. Your `like` expressions (e.g., `'%xxx%'` ) do not meet that requirement.

As a result, while the join criteria may well have a covering index, nothing else does and so a table scan of the join tables is required.

In a nutshell, there is no way to fix performance outside of either

- rethinking what you're doing, or
- using something like a full text search

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  tblResources_NEW.ResourceID
    ,tblResources_NEW.ProjectFile
    ,tblResources_NEW.ResourceFile
    ,tblResources_NEW.ResourceName
    ,tblResourcesTranslated_NEW.Culture
    ,tblResourcesTranslated_NEW.TranslatedFlag
    ,tblResourcesTranslated_NEW.TranslatedValue
    ,tblResources_NEW.Comments
    ,tblResources_NEW.IsApproved
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        tblResources_NEW.ResourceID
        ,tblResources_NEW.ProjectFile
        ,tblResources_NEW.ResourceFile
        ,tblResources_NEW.ResourceName
        ,tblResources_NEW.Comments
        ,tblResources_NEW.IsApproved
    FROM tblResources_NEW
    WHERE
        tblResources_NEW.ResourceID like '%'+ @input + '%' 
        OR tblResources_NEW.ProjectFile like '%'+ @input + '%' 
        OR tblResources_NEW.ResourceFile like '%'+ @input + '%' 
        OR tblResources_NEW.ResourceName like '%'+ @input + '%' 
        OR tblResources_NEW.ResourceValue like '%'+ @input + '%' 
        OR tblResources_NEW.Comments like '%'+ @input + '%'
    ) AS tblResources_NEW
INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT 
tblResourcesTranslated_NEW.ResourceID
        ,tblResourcesTranslated_NEW.Culture
        ,tblResourcesTranslated_NEW.TranslatedFlag
        ,tblResourcesTranslated_NEW.TranslatedValue
    FROM tblResourcesTranslated_NEW
    WHERE 
        tblResourcesTranslated_NEW.Uid like '%'+ @input + '%' 
        OR tblResourcesTranslated_NEW.TranslatedValue like '%'+ @input + '%'
    ) AS tblResourcesTranslated_NEW ON tblResourcesTranslated_NEW.ResourceID=tblResources_NEW.ResourceID
```

Comment: sure looks nicer - but how is this gonna help? you're causing the same full table scans as before...

Comment: Thanks for the help! when I try this it shows the column name tblResourcesTranslated_NEW.ResourceID is invalid in the last line, I wonder why? I checked and I'm pretty sure there is no typo and the column does exist in that table....

Comment: True Linky, the table scans are still there but if he has to grab this data and limit this data then we aren't going to get around those scans, correct? This could potentially limit the aggregation/joins that the server will need to perform by limitting the resultset BEFORE the join.

Comment: Try that, I forgot to grab the resourceId in both query sets. The answer to this question will all depend on your query plan. You could post that which would be helpful.

Comment: Unless I'm missing a drastic change, this should be done by the compiler in the original query as well, its execution plan should be pretty much the same. 
The problem is that you have to run a FTS on one table at first and then you MAY be able to limit the resultset in the second table. But only if 1) subselA massively reduced reduced the resultset and 2) resourceId is indexed and 3) the optimizer thinks that waiting for previous results and using them is cheaper than running 2 tables scans in the first place (but again - this should be the case in the original query as well)

Comment: Yea Link, I can see it going several directions. Without a query plan to look at we're both just stabbing fools in the dark. You and I share the fact that we wouldn't be doing this in production anyway. However if you have two tables with a million rows a piece and you need to do an operation like this, limiting the results before joining them will help performance (period). Now of course if you're running normal query with the correct indexes, the optimizer should do this all for you but it CAN'T limit the results in this example effectively.

Comment: I guess we're on the same page. What I try to getting at is that there's no guarantee that rewriting like you did results in reduce/join. If you have a good db design you almost never need it as the optimizer detects itself. If you have a bad design and no/crappy indices you likely don't need it either. And in the cases in between they can help achieve the desired outcome pretty much the same as placing additional filters in a join instead of where or reordering the query: by luck that you're pushing the optimizer in the right direction (which can change back without further notice)

Answer (score 0):

If You insist on having one input for all fields, I would at least boost some performance by doing dynamic SQL.

```
Alter PROCEDURE LRMWEB_Search
(
    @input nvarchar(1500)
)

   AS

     declare @sql varchar(2000);


    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    set @sql = 'SELECT 
          tblResources_NEW.ResourceID, 
          tblResources_NEW.ProjectFile, 
          tblResources_NEW.ResourceFile, 
          tblResources_NEW.ResourceName, 
          tblResourcesTranslated_NEW.Culture, 
          tblResourcesTranslated_NEW.TranslatedFlag, 
          tblResourcesTranslated_NEW.TranslatedValue, 
          tblResources_NEW.Comments, 
          tblResources_NEW.IsApproved
     FROM 
          tblResourcesTranslated_NEW INNER JOIN 
          tblResources_NEW ON tblResourcesTranslated_NEW.ResourceID=tblResources_NEW.ResourceID
     where ';


    -- here I would concatenate all your string conditions 
    if (ISNUMERIC(@input)= 0)
    Begin
         . . . . . . . 
    End
    -- here I would concatenate all your numeric conditions   
   if (ISNUMERIC(@input)= 1)
   Begin
       set @sql = @sql + ' OR tblResources_NEW.ResourceID like ''%@1%''';
       . . . . . 
   End

   -- call to execute
   EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@1 varchar', @1 = @input;
```

This should give you at least some boost by excluding unneeded searches. But really, you should do something like this by using single parameter for every condition. Than you can exclude those that are `Null` from building into string.

But, again, this design is `BAD`.

Comment: This is open to sql injection...and the dynamic sql could make it slower as it needs to be recompiled while filters aren't reducing the load (besides the isnumeric)

Comment: @Linky That supposed to work since there is only 1 parameter but parameters can also be compiled dynamically :o))

Comment: yeah I know; that's why I was wondering you were recommending dynamic sql that is open to injection and can't be reused. Thanks for the change.